# Regarding derivation of Acoustic wave equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics

Is it correct to start deriving the acoustic wave equation by assuming the speed of the fluid at every point is very small ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you mean the particle velocity of the fluid is very small compared to the acoustic wave speed, then yes, that is typically one of the initial assumptions.